# Why do pros patrol workers when trying to block buildings?

Tags: starcraft-2

The best example is trying to block a zerg early hatchery. Most pros will set their worker to patrol in a small area to block the hatchery. Why not hold position or just "stop"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Patrolling keeps the worker from getting killed easily, while still blocking the area.

And it's more efficient than manually moving around, you can let it 'patrol' and move on with your business.

Comment: By melee units with similar speeds, anyway.

Comment: Exactly, talking about worker vs. worker

Comment: +1 Actually, they normally do it manually with way points, but its for the exact same reason.  To take fewer hits from chasing workers

Answer (score 8):

Patrolling the worker also prevents it from showing up as idle. This way, any idle workers that are selected can actually be used for something else.

Comment: Haha the funny thing is, I patrol my intentionally-idle workers instinctively, but I forgot why I started that habit. You just reminded me why.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that the patrol gets the probe up to speed, so that they don't need to accelerate for further movements, such as the little way needed to move the probe to perfect position when building the expand. I might be wrong though.

Comment: wow I had never considered this... very good point.

Answer (score -2):

Yet another reason is that a patrolling worker will attack other workers that come near it (IIRC). An idle worker will just run away, which means they're no longer blocking. Whereas if they send a worker to build a building where your patrolling worker is, I believe your worker will attack theirs, and if they don't notice it, could even kill it.

Edit: As the comments indicate, I might not be right about workers attacking when set on patrol. I haven't tried it lately.

Comment: Why -1? Is the answer wrong? If it's not, it seems useful.

Comment: The -1 is probably because this isn't true. Patrolling workers do *not* attack automatically.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. Why +1 then? :)